# how to find classifier list in weka

Tags: weka

I want to use Weka to do linear regression. I have already writing the java program to create a .arff dataset with all input features. I opened the .arff file. Under classify, I click "choose" under classifier and tried to find the linear regression but it is blank. I know it is suppose to have a list of algorithms when click choose, but I found blank page. I would like to know is there anything wrong with my operation or my weka installation?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a drop down window with a list of classifiers. You may want to check your Weka installation, Java installation, and maybe your resolution / dpi scaling (maybe try a lower resolution if you are on a high dpi screen, or 100% / normal dpi scaling) to see if there is a problem with the way Weka is rendering the GUI.

[image: Weka Choose Classifier]

Comment: I actually just tried the .arff files in data folder in the weka installation folder. I found I can see the classifier list in these sample .arff files but I cannot see any thing in the .arff I generated.

Comment: I use the sample .arff file to open the .arff file my java program generate and I can see the classifier list now.

Comment: Well then it sounds like your ARFF file is not correct. You should edit your question and post the header, make sure you have an relation, some attributes, data.. etc.